# Xamarin Forms - Webview page's click and horizontal scroll is not working

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, android-webview, custom-renderer

I have a webview in Xamarin Forms app for render html content and privacy policy. I'am facing two issues, that are follows.

- Content page or page popups are not respond to the click action.
- Images are displayed in the page are in bigger size and I'am not able to scroll those image horizontally.

**Note:** In iOS everything is working fine, no issues.

Pleas see my droid render implementation.

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (null == e.OldElement)
    {
        var webView = Element as CustomWebView;
        Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
        Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        Control.Settings.EnableSmoothTransition();
        Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        Control.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient(webView));
        Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        Control.LoadUrl(control.Uri);
    }
}
```

I have tried different options but no luck. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please disable `DispatchTouchEvent` method. Just use `webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort=true;` in your `WebViewRenderer`, webview could be horizontal scrolled. Here is running GIF. https://imgur.com/a/zUD16pf

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks. Working fine. Please post as an answer, so that I can mark your answer.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I felt little bit jerky effect while scrolling horizontally, is there any workaround.

Comment: This little bit jerky effect may be related to the Android emulator, you can test it in Android device.

Comment: I post above comment to answer, please accept it as answer, it will help other who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable DispatchTouchEvent method.Just use `webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort=true;` in your `WebViewRenderer`.
You can use following code in your `WebViewRenderer`

```
 var webView = (global::Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
 webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort=true;
```

If I have long button. if I add this attribute, here is running GIF.

[image]